# Fundamental solutions for degenerate elliptic equations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am looking for a paper or a book that says about the existence and some estimates (like these in the non-degenerate case) of the fundamental solutions for degenerate elliptic equations $L = -divA\nabla$ over the domain ${\mathbb R}^{n+1}_+$, where $\lambda^{-1}\omega(x)\xi^2 \leq A(x)\xi\xi \leq \lambda\omega(x)\xi^2$ and $\omega \in A_2$

Wheeden and Chanillo had some kind of that results but only for bounded domain (they called Green function) on their paper "[Existence and estimates of Greens functions for degenerate elliptic equations](http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1988_4_15_2_309_0.pdf)." However, they did not have the estimates for the size or the smoothness of the Green function.

Thanks.

Update: It looks like the problem is still untouched and we may not have fundamental solution for unbounded domain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. Some of the equations and symbols here are, at least for me, un-decipherable. Can you explain what are $\xi, \lambda, A_2$ and $\omega$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interesting reference, https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05583.
This is not about Green's function, but about sobolev space estimates. Maybe this could be useful/interesting for you.

This paper looks at the equation you are interested in.